# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object when running a sorting function

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple sorting function for 3 inputs, and I've managed to do so when all inputs are unique.

However, I'm encountering issues when 2 of the 3 inputs are the same, more specifically, when the 2nd and 3rd input are the same. I get the following issue: 
`TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`

What does this mean and how can it be fixed?

```
def simple_sort_version2(a,b,c):
    if a > b and a > c:
        if b > c:
            return c,b,a
        elif c > b:
            return b,c,a
    elif b > a and b > c:
        if a > c:
            return c,a,b
        elif c > a:
            return a,c,b
    elif c > a and c > b:
        if a > b:
            return b,a,c
        elif b > a:
            return a,b,c
    elif a == b:
        if a > c:
            return c,a,b
        elif c > a:
            return a,b,c
    elif a == c:
        if a > b:
            return b,a,c
        elif b > a:
            return a,c,b
    elif b == c:
        if b > a:
            return a,b,c
        elif a > b:
            return b,c,a

a,b,c = simple_sort_version2(10,20,30)
print (a,b,c) # 10 20 30

a,b,c = simple_sort_version2(10,30,20)
print (a,b,c) # 10 20 30

a,b,c = simple_sort_version2(30,20,10)
print (a,b,c) # 10 20 30

a,b,c = simple_sort_version2(30,20,20)
print (a,b,c) # 20 20 30
```

Comment: Did you try any sort of debugging? This is actually an easy case because the problem is in your first `if`. I would suggest even working with a paper and pen to figure out where is the problem. A hint: if a function does not reach an explicit `return`, it will automatically return `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>>print(simple_sort_version2(30,20,20))
   None
```

since `a>b` and `a>c`
your code enters the first `if-statement`
Then it returns `None` because there is no `b==c` case.

Note that:

> If there is no return statement python returns `None` by default
>
> The code can not go to the last `elif-statement` because it already entered the first `if-statement`